# Circular Correlation in Theano

Tags: python, correlation, theano

I'm trying to compute [circular cross-correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Circular_convolution_theorem_and_cross-correlation_theorem) of two signals with Theano to use it in further calculation of loss that I would optimize over. But I'm not quite sure how to do that.

It is defined as following:

```
(f * g)[n] = sum_k f[k]g[k+n]
ccc[n] = \sum_k (f*g)[n-kN]
```

- "periodic" summation or like "for each k-th component".

I could do an ordinary correlation and then perform periodic summation, but it's not quite clear how to do that (periodic summation) symbolically (using scan, probably?)

```
conv2d = T.signal.conv.conv2d

x = T.dmatrix()
y = T.dmatrix()
veclen = x.shape[1]

corr_expr = conv2d(x, y[:, ::-1], image_shape=(1, veclen), border_mode='full')

# circ_corr = T.sum([corr_expr[k::veclen] for k in T.arange(veclen)])

corr = theano.function([x, y], outputs=circ_corr)

corr( np.array([[2, 3, 5]]), np.array([[7, 11, 13]]) )
```

or use circular cross-correlation theorem and compute as a iFFT(FFT(x)*FFT(y)):

```
import theano.sandbox.fourier as dft
x = T.dmatrix()
y = T.dvector()
veclen = x.shape[1]

exp = T.real( 
        dft.ifft( 
            dft.fft(x, veclen, axis=1) 
            * dft.fft(y[::-1], y.shape[0], axis=1).reshape((1, -1)), 
            veclen, axis=1
        ) 
    )[:, ::-1]
f = theano.function([x, y], outputs=exp)

f(np.array([[2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 4], [5, 6, 7]]), np.array([7, 11, 13]) )
```

but in this case I can't actually compute a gradient because gradient for ifft (and all functions that has something to do with complex numbers in general, afaik) is not implemented yet, I guess (aborts with an error: `Elemwise{real,no_inplace}.grad illegally  returned an integer-valued variable. (Input index 0, dtype complex128)`)

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site but you have not stated a question. It is not clear what you and your code are trying to achieve. What is the point? What is wrong with this code? What error messages are you getting, if applicable? What are example inputs and their expected outputs?

Comment: @DanielRenshaw , okay, I thought that title "Circular Correlation in Theano" is quite self-explanatory :)

Comment: I think the chances of finding somebody on StackOverflow who is familiar with circular correlation, familiar with Theano, and has time to read and interpret your code, is quite slim! Providing more supporting material/links/etc. would help people who only partially meet those requirements to contribute.

Comment: @DanielRenshaw , agree, thank you, done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working solution I came up with (definitely not optimal as soon as FFT is not used):

```
def circular_crosscorelation(X, y):
    """ 
    Input:
        symbols for X [n, m]
        and y[m,]

    Returns: 
        symbol for circular cross corelation of each of row in X with 
        cc[n, m]
    """
    n, m = X.shape
    corr_expr = T.signal.conv.conv2d(X, y[::-1].reshape((1, -1)), image_shape=(1, m), border_mode='full')
    corr_len = corr_expr.shape[1]
    pad = m - corr_len%m
    v_padded = T.concatenate([corr_expr, T.zeros((n, pad))], axis=1)
    circ_corr_exp = T.sum(v_padded.reshape((n, v_padded.shape[1] / m, m)), axis=1)
    return circ_corr_exp[:, ::-1]

X = T.dmatrix()
y = T.dmatrix()
cc = theano.function([X, y], circular_crosscorelation(X, y))
print cc( np.array([[2, 3, 5], [4, 5, 6]]), np.array([[7, 11, 13]]) )
```

returns

```
[[  94.  108.  108.]
 [ 149.  157.  159.]]
```

as expected.

And can be analytically differentiated:

```
score = T.sum(circ_corr_exp**2)
grad = T.grad(score, x)
g = theano.function([x, y], outputs=grad)
print g( np.array([[2, 3, 5], [4, 5, 6]]), np.array([[7, 11, 13]]) )

>> [[ 6332.  6388.  6500.]
>>  [ 9554.  9610.  9666.]]
```

---

here's also few more options (through direct circulant calculation) and time-comparation:

```
def circulant_np(v):
    row = np.arange(len(v))
    col = -np.arange(len(v))
    idx = (row[:, np.newaxis] + col)%len(v)
    return v[idx]

print circulant_np(np.array([1, 2, 3, 5]))

def c_corr_np(a, b):
    return circulant_np(a).dot(b[::-1])

def circulant_t(v):
    row = T.arange(v.shape[0])
    col = -T.arange(v.shape[0])
    idx = (row.reshape((-1, 1)) + col)%v.shape[0]
    return v[idx]

def c_corr_t_f(a, b):
    """ 1d correlation using circulant matrix """
    return circulant_t(a).dot(b[::-1])

a = T.dvector('a')
b = T.dvector('b')
c_corr_t = theano.function([a, b], c_corr_t_f(a, b))

print c_corr_np(np.array([2, 3, 5]), np.array([7, 11, 13]))
print c_corr_t(np.array([2, 3, 5]), np.array([7, 11, 13]))
print c_corr( np.array([[2, 3, 5]]), np.array([[7, 11, 13]]) )

%timeit c_corr_np(np.array([2, 3, 5]), np.array([7, 11, 13]))
%timeit c_corr_t(np.array([2, 3, 5]), np.array([7, 11, 13]))
%timeit c_corr( np.array([[2, 3, 5]]), np.array([[7, 11, 13]]) ) # = circular_crosscorelation
```

which gives

```
10000 loops, best of 3: 30.6 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 132 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 149 µs per loop
```

and inverse cross-corr:

```
def inverse_circular_crosscorelation(y):
    """ 
    Input:
        symbol for y[1, m]

    Returns: 
        symbol for y_inv s.t. 
        cc( y, y_inv ) = (1, 0 ... 0)
    """

    A = circulant_t(y.reshape((-1, )))
    b = T.concatenate([T.zeros((y.shape[1] - 1, )), T.ones((1, ))]).reshape((-1, 1))
    return T.nlinalg.matrix_inverse(A).dot(b).reshape((1, -1))[:, ::-1]
```

Comment: I'm also trying to make it in theano, but I want to compute the circular correlation row-wise between two matrices of same dimensions, i.e. c_corr(A[0,:],B[0,:]), c_corr(A[1,:],B[1,:]),... But in just one function, because I also need to compute the gradients w.r.t to A, and B. And I'm having a hard time doing it, any idea?

Comment: Made it with a scan in the end, but still this quadratic way of doing it is very slow, we should implement the gradients for fft and ifft to get it in n.log(n), if I have time some day.